# Can we uncheck any build step from Run custom build in teamcity

Tags: testing, build, teamcity

Is there a way to disable any build step on run time. Like we have option to un-check a step when that Run pop comes up in team city. E.g we have tests that run with every build but due to some urgent build we want to uncheck them from Run button instead of disabling the build step from build configuration.

Go through the build feature option but it is also not giving any such thing. Any idea is that thing possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sam! Did the answers below assist at all? If so, I wonder if you would consider replying to them, voting on them, or accepting one of them?

Comment: With regrets, downvoted - see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a direct button to "uncheck" a build step .However, you can handle it in many ways

1. You can copy an build target and remove /disable the specific steps.
2. You can parameterize your steps so that if you select /deselect a checkbox a specific build step won't run.
3. You can also break your build targets into multiple targets, for ex build will be a target and test will be a target . If you want to skip testing, just stop or pause the target
4. You can also deactivate a specific build step in a build target via edit configuration

---

Another way would be to add check boxes for each step that are always selected by default. In each of the build steps that you want to be optional , read the corresponding checkbox  property . If it is set proceed with the corresponding build else skip the step.

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge the closest feature to what was described would be running certain build steps based on a condition (the most common is variable value). Unfortunately, this feature is not available yet: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939

As you can see from the link above, JetBrains is on its track to implement it and you actually can find some techniques to achieve desired in the comment section there but the feature itself is going to be introduced most likely in version 9.0.